# What format gives photorec to files?

Tags: linux, usb, data-recovery

I have to recover a file from my usb. I didn't find it on the net. How does photorec call files of unknown format? For instance, I have a file named *.jks . How can I find it in the recovered directory? Is it yet recovered? And what is its format?

Answer (score 1):

1) How to use photorec step by step

```
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step
```

2) You can select format. Available formats

```
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/File_Formats_Recovered_By_PhotoRec
```

3) You can add your own format

```
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Add_your_own_extension_to_PhotoRec
```

4) To access your files from a normal user account, you should change the rights by changing the directory from owner and are content with the chown command, for example

```
 chown -R Linux:Linux /home/Linux/recup
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But still, what should I write to add format? I tried "fidentify jks 0 0xBYTES_OF_FILE" and "fidentify jks 0 "SOMETEXTFROMFILE"". But none of this worked. It still shows as unknown.

Comment: example (http://techglimpse.com/photorec-recover-add-specific-file-type/  )